# Android Spinner with different Value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I created a spinner in my xml with the options `permanent` and `temp` and when the user clicks on it, it has to add to my azure database, the only problem i am facing is that if the user clicks `permanent` it must add a `1` to my database and if the user clicks `temp` it must add a `0` to my database

Here is my strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="customerstatus">

        <item>permanent</item>
        <item>temporary</item>

    </string-array>
```

Comment: Since you can use onItemChangeListener, and act accordingly. Where are you facing problem ?

Comment: @NightFury so im sort of new to spinners so the only way i know how to do it is in the `strings.xml` i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("permanent")) {
                 // Value should be 1 
            } else if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("temp")) {
                 // Value should be 0 
            }
        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }           
    });
```

You can also add dynamic values in spinner through code as explained here

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String [] {"USA", "Europe"});

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```